# How do I use the json library?

Tags: json, haskell

I'm trying to figure out Haskell's [json](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/json) library.  However, I'm running into a bit of an issue in ghci:

```
Prelude> import Text.JSON
Prelude Text.JSON> decode "[1,2,3]"

<interactive>:1:0:
    Ambiguous type variable `a' in the constraint:
      `JSON a' arising from a use of `decode' at <interactive>:1:0-15
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

I think this has something to do with the a in the type signature:

```
decode :: JSON a => String -> Result a
```

Can someone show me:

1. How to decode a string?
2. What's going with the type system here?

Comment: Shouldn't you be decoding a string such as `({"key":[1,2,3]})` instead of a flat out array?

Comment: @meder - There's no reason why I would have to, but an object would (should?) work just as well.  It's just something I chose because it was easy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify which type you want to get back, like this:

```
decode "[1,2,3]" :: Result [Integer]
-- Ok [1,2,3]
```

If that line was part of a larger program where you would go on and use the result of `decode` the type could just be inferred, but since ghci doesn't know which type you need, it can't infer it.

It's the same reason why `read "[1,2,3]"` doesn't work without a type annotation or more context.

Comment: The only problem is that JSON is dynamically typed, which means I might not know the type ahead of time.  The json library comes with a JSValue type that you can use instead:  `decode "[1,2,3]" :: Result [JSValue]` gives
`Ok [JSRational False (1 % 1),JSRational False (2 % 1),JSRational False (3 % 1)]`.  Other than that, this is the correct approach as far as I can tell.

Comment: ...or even better than that:  `decode "[1,2,3]" :: Result JSValue` gives `Ok (JSArray [JSRational False (1 % 1),JSRational False (2 % 1),JSRational False (3 % 1)])`.

Comment: You've hit on the crux of the matter. Haskell is not dynamically typed, so if you want a way to represent unknown types, you need some wrapper datatype that can capture all of them. JSValue seems to serve that purpose here.

Answer (score 4):

The decode function is defined as follows:

```
decode :: JSON a => String -> Result a
```

In a real program, the type inference engine can usually figure out what type to expect from decode.  For example:

```
userAge :: String -> Int
userAge input = case decode input of
                  Result a -> a
                  _ -> error $ "Couldn't parse " ++ input
```

In this case, the type of `userAge` causes the typechecker to infer that decode's return value, in this particular case, is `Result Int`.

However, when you use `decode` in GHCi, you must specify the type of the value, e.g.:

```
decode "6" :: Result Int
=> Ok 6
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick glance at the docs seems to suggest that the purpose of this function is to allow you to read JSON into any Haskell data structure of a supported type, so

```
decode "[1, 2, 3]" :: Result [Int]
```

ought to work